# how can I insert a div between the two div?

Tags: jquery

> I have the following html...

```
<div id="one"></div>
<div id="two"></div>
```

I want to insert a `<div id="test"></div>` like this by selecting $('#two') selector

Result:

```
<div id="one"></div>
<div id="test"></div>
<div id="two"></div>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [.insertBefore()](http://api.jquery.com/insertBefore/)

```
$('<div id="test" />').insertBefore('#two')
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/AD3UE/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.after()` or `.before()` with jQuery to do exactly what you're chasing.

`$('#one').after('<div id="test"></div>');`

or

`$('#two').before('<div id="test"></div>');`

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$( "#two").before( "<div id="test"></div>" );
```

Answer (score 0):

Please create DOM elements correctly

```
$('<div>').attr('id', 'test').insertBefore('#two');
```

Answer (score 0):

This is another answer

```
$("<div id="test"></div>").insertAfter('$one')
```